# The SPListItem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy

I'm facing the issues on SPO(SharePoint Online).

Any one can explain why this error occurred?

> The SPListItem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy
>   fields

Have any solution to Fix?

Please let me know step by step.

Download as a template and One of my Fields below from manifest.xml.

```
 <Field ID="{b8a02c27-2a46-4153-9134-9a63f68a3729}" Name="SAEFSecurityClassificationTaxHTField0" StaticName="SAEFSecurityClassificationTaxHTField0" DisplayName="Security Classification_0" Type="Note" Required="FALSE" ShowInViewForms="FALSE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" Overwrite="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" Customization="" Version="4" AllowDeletion="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" ColName="ntext2" RowOrdinal="0"/>
<Field ID="{2ce2f798-4e95-48f9-a317-73f854109466}" Name="SAEFSecurityClassification" StaticName="SAEFSecurityClassification" Group="Shell Document Columns" DisplayName="Security Classification" Type="TaxonomyFieldType" ShowField="Term1033" Required="TRUE" Mult="FALSE" Overwrite="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInFileDlg="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" List="{08309df3-77b0-406a-a08a-a91f306d2d20}" WebId="3a8de7a5-f7e1-41ca-9ab6-717476915a69" Customization="" Version="7" AllowDeletion="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" ColName="int2" RowOrdinal="0">
  <Default>15;#Unrestricted|a6bcf75a-a979-458c-83c1-40defbdcf8ae</Default>
  <Customization>
    <ArrayOfProperty>
      <Property>
        <Name>SspId</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q1:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">f6342a3a-e960-4137-a44a-2b1219963d10</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>GroupId</Name>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>TermSetId</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">daf890f0-167e-4ee2-a9fd-a81536ed8167</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>AnchorId</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q3:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>UserCreated</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q4:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>Open</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q5:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>TextField</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{b8a02c27-2a46-4153-9134-9a63f68a3729}</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>IsPathRendered</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q7="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q7:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>IsKeyword</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q8="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q8:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>TargetTemplate</Name>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>CreateValuesInEditForm</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q9="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q9:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>FilterAssemblyStrongName</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q10="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q10:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>FilterClassName</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q11="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q11:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>FilterMethodName</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q12="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q12:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">GetFilteringHtml</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>FilterJavascriptProperty</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q13="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q13:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">FilteringJavascript</Value>
      </Property>
    </ArrayOfProperty>
  </Customization>
</Field>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the error you are getting!!!

Comment: Error Like "The SPListItem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields."

Comment: instead of hard-coding the values, can you use tokens ? check this link - [PnP Core Component Provisioning Engine Tokens](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/dev/Core/ProvisioningEngineTokens.md)

Comment: values we could not change that is default.